# GCP - Eventarc not triggering Cloud Run - permission_denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-run, event-arc

I have configured Eventarc to listen for event like -
`google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob`

It was working fine until a few days back.
When an insert operation takes place in BigQuery, Eventarc was triggering a Cloud Run application which in turn published a message to a pub-sub queue.

The problem I have been facing since it stopped working is that Eventarc is no longer triggering the Cloud Run App.
I can see the events in cloud logging, but there is no follow-up action in Eventarc.

[image]

I tried adding all recommended permissions in excess as well.

[image]

Any input on what I might be missing, or where to look would be very much helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if `roles/eventarc.eventReceiver` permission is also added as per this documentation on [Eventarc Roles and permissions for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/roles-permissions)?